# multiprocessing with moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

Recently I made a script that take a 5 minutes video clip and cuts for 5 video, 1 min each video, it works well, but its taking too long for pc like my, and my pc with very good part performance:

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2904 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16
> Logical Processor(s)
>
> Installed Physical Memory (RAM)   16.0 GB

So I search on the moviepy's docs "threads", I found something in the "write_videofile" function that i can set my threads to speed up, I tried it, but its didnt worked, I mean its worked but its only it changed maybe to more 2 or 3 it/s.

Also I found example code with multithreading but its seems like the code doesnt work because moviepy.multithreading doesnt exists in the moviepy library, Please help me speed up the rendering,
Thank you

here is the code that i found:

```py
from moviepy.multithreading import multithread_write_videofile

def concat_clips():
    files = [
        "myclip1.mp4",
        "myclip2.mp4",
        "myclip3.mp4",
        "myclip4.mp4",
    ]
    multithread_write_videofile("output.mp4", get_final_clip, {"files": files})


def get_final_clip(files):
    clips = [VideoFileClip(file) for file in files]
    final = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
    return final
```

this is my code:

```py
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
from moviepy.editor import *
from numpy import array, true_divide
import cv2
import time


# ffmpeg_extract_subclip("full.mp4", start_seconds, end_seconds, targetname="cut.mp4")




def duration_clip(filename):
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
    duration = clip.duration
    return duration


current_time = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")


def main():
    global duration
    start = 0
    cut_name_num = 1
    end_seconds = start + 60
    video_duration = duration_clip("video.mp4")
    


    txt = input("Enter Your text please: ") [::-1]
    txt_part = 1

    while start < int(video_duration):
        final_text = f"{str(txt_part)} {txt}"



        try:
            try:
                os.makedirs(f"result_{str(current_time)}/result_edit")
            except FileExistsError:
                pass            
            ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video.mp4", start, end_seconds, targetname=f"result_{str(current_time)}/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

            clip = VideoFileClip(f"result_{str(current_time)}/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

            clip = clip.subclip(0, 60)

            clip = clip.volumex(2)

            txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize = 50, color = 'white')

            txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60) 

            video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])
            
            clip.write_videofile(f"result_{str(current_time)}/result_edit/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

        except:
            try:
                os.makedirs(f"result_{str(current_time)}/result_edit")
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
            
            ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video.mp4", start, video_duration, targetname=f"result_{str(current_time)}/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

            clip_duration = duration_clip(f"result_{str(current_time)}/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

            clip = VideoFileClip(f"result_{str(current_time)}/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

            clip = clip.subclip(0, clip_duration)

            clip = clip.volumex(2)

            txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize = 50, color = 'white')

            txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60) 

            video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])

            clip.write_videofile(f"result_{str(current_time)}/result_edit/cut_{str(cut_name_num)}.mp4")

        start += 60
        cut_name_num += 1
        end_seconds = start + 60
        txt_part += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm wondering how it can possible to concatenate files in threads. As for me you can't start writing second file before you finish writing first file so second file depends on first file and there is no place to split it in to two threads. You can split problem if you have to cut file because created files doesn't depens each other. But maybe with multiprocessing it will run faster then with threading. But I'm wondering how fast it would be if you would use directly ffmpeg or ffmpeg-python.

Comment: How can i do it with multiprocessing ?

Comment: first you have to create function with code which you can run separatelly - ie. code which you run in `while`-loop  - code after `final_text = ...` and before `start +=  60`. And first try to run it as function - you will see if you have to use some parameters to run this function. And later you can try to run this function with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: you repeate the same code but with different values in `try` and `except`. If you would use `if/else` to test values `start`, video_duration, etc then code would be shorter and more readable. BTW: in newer Python you can use `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` and then you don't need to use `try/except`

Comment: if you use `f-string` then you don't need `str()`

Comment: ok i didnt know, Let's go over what I did, i created a function that rendering the video, the parameters (filename, txt) now i am getting involved with the multiprocessing can you help me please?

Comment: you need something more then `(filename, txt)` - you need `(filename, txt, start, end, cut_name_num, txt_part)` because `process` doesn't have access to variables in main process. BTW: variable `cut_name_num`, `txt_part` have always the same values so you could use one variable i.e. `number`

Comment: What do you mean start, end?

Comment: to create subclip you need values `start, end_seconds` and you have to send it also to function.

Comment: do you need subclip without text? I think it could work faster if you wouldn't write it and read it again.

Comment: The text is must. Ok i understand you

Comment: But the question is how can i do that each processor will work for other file from the other processor?, i tried to do something with this but its confusing me i dont know how can i switch the processor to work about other file after he is ended with his first file

Comment: if you use loop which will use `Process()` to start function with different arguments then it will run all processes at the same time and you don't have to switch anything.  If you use `Pool(8)` and put list with arguments for all processes then it will run 8 processes at the same time - when one process will finish job then it will automatically run next process from list - and you don't have to switch anything. I'm testing both version - but on my computer it reduces only 20 seconds because `ffmpeg` already uses full CPU power for single process and there is no power to run other faster,

Comment: Can u send me an example please, I dont really know this library good.

Comment: I start describing it in answer. You see it after few minutes.

Comment: Ok thank you, Waiting for you answer...

Comment: I added answer with few versions. I wondering if you plan to join all subclips to one video - because it may be faster to do it all in one process using single `VideoFileClip` with many `TextClip` which will have different `.set_start(start)` and `CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip1, txt_clip2, txt_clip3, ...])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using processes I reduced time only by 15-20 seconds because `ffmpeg` even in single process was using almost full CPU power and my computer didn't have power to run other processes faster.

---

First I reduced code to make it shorter.

Code in `try` and `except` had similar elements so I moved them ouside `try/except`.

Next I used

```
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration
```

and I didn't need `try/except` at all.

Using `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)` I don't need to run it in `try/except`

Meanwhile I reduced time by 20 seconds using

```
        clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(start, end)
```

instead of

```
        temp_filename  = f"{base_folder}/cut_{number}.mp4"
        
        fmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, start, end, targetname=temp_filename)
        
        clip = VideoFileClip(temp_filename)
```

This way I don't write subclip on disk and I don't have to read it again from disk.

---

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
from moviepy.editor import *
import time

def main():

    text = input("Enter Your text please: ") [::-1]
    #text = 'Hello World'
    
    base_folder = time.strftime("result_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")    
    os.makedirs(f"{base_folder}/result_edit", exist_ok=True)
    
    filename = "video.mp4"
    #filename = "BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    
    video_duration = VideoFileClip(filename).duration

    number = 0 # instead of `cut_name_num` and `txt_part` because both had the same value

    time_start = time.time()

    for start in range(0, int(video_duration), 60):

        end = start + 60
        
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration

        number += 1

        clip_duration = end - start
        print(f'[DEBUG] number: {number:2} | start: {start:6.2f} | end: {end:6.2f} | duration: {clip_duration:.2f}')
       
        final_text = f"{number} {text}"
    
        temp_filename  = f"{base_folder}/cut_{number}.mp4"
        final_filename = f"{base_folder}/result_edit/cut_{number}.mp4"
        
        #ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, start, end, targetname=temp_filename)
        
        #clip = VideoFileClip(temp_filename)
        clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(start, end)
        clip = clip.volumex(2)
    
        txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize=50, color='white')
        txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60)
        
        video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])
    
        video.write_videofile(final_filename)

    # - after loop -
    
    # because I use `number += 1` before loop so now `number` has number of subclips
    print('number of subclips:', number)

    time_end = time.time()
    
    diff = time_end - time_start
    print(f'time: {diff:.2f}s ({diff//60:02.0f}:{diff%60:02.2f})')
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Next I moved code to function with arguments `my_process(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder)`

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
from moviepy.editor import *
import time

def my_process(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder):

    clip_duration = end - start
    print(f'[DEBUG] number: {number:2} | start: {start:6.2f} | end: {end:6.2f} | duration: {clip_duration:.2f}')
    
    final_text = f"{number} {text}"

    temp_filename  = f"{base_folder}/cut_{number}.mp4"
    final_filename = f"{base_folder}/result_edit/cut_{number}.mp4"
    
    #print('[DEBUG] ffmpeg_extract_subclip')
    #ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, start, end, targetname=temp_filename)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] VideoClip')
    #clip = VideoFileClip(temp_filename)
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(start, end)
    clip = clip.volumex(2)

    #print('[DEBUG] TextClip')
    txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize=50, color='white')
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip')
    video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])

    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip write')
    video.write_videofile(final_filename)
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip end')
    

def main():

    text = input("Enter Your text please: ") [::-1]
    #text = 'Hello World'
    
    base_folder = time.strftime("result_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")    
    os.makedirs(f"{base_folder}/result_edit", exist_ok=True)
    
    filename = "video.mp4"
    #filename = "BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    
    video_duration = VideoFileClip(filename).duration

    number = 0 # instead of `cut_name_num` and `txt_part` because both had the same value

    time_start = time.time()
    
    for start in range(0, int(video_duration), 60):

        end = start + 60
        
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration
        
        number += 1
        
        my_process(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder)
        
    # - after loop -
    
    # because I use `number += 1` before loop so now `number` has number of subclips
    print('number of subclips:', number)

    time_end = time.time()
    
    diff = time_end - time_start
    print(f'time: {diff:.2f}s ({diff//60:02.0f}:{diff%60:02.2f})')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And now I can run function in separated processes using standard module [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html)

(or standard modules [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or external modules [Joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.Parallel.html), [Ray](https://ray.io/), etc.).

It starts single process

```
# it has to use named arguments`target=`, `args=`

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process, args=(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder))
p.start()  # start it
```

but if I use it in loop then I will start many processes at the same time.

---

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
from moviepy.editor import *
import time
import multiprocessing

def my_process(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder):

    clip_duration = end - start
    print(f'[DEBUG] number: {number:2} | start: {start:6.2f} | end: {end:6.2f} | duration: {clip_duration:.2f}')
    
    final_text = f"{number} {text}"

    temp_filename  = f"{base_folder}/cut_{number}.mp4"
    final_filename = f"{base_folder}/result_edit/cut_{number}.mp4"
    
    #print('[DEBUG] ffmpeg_extract_subclip')
    #ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, start, end, targetname=temp_filename)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] VideoClip')
    #clip = VideoFileClip(temp_filename)
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(start, end)
    clip = clip.volumex(2)

    #print('[DEBUG] TextClip')
    txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize=50, color='white')
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip')
    video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])

    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip write')
    video.write_videofile(final_filename)
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip end')
    

def main():

    text = input("Enter Your text please: ") [::-1]
    #text = 'Hello World'
    
    base_folder = time.strftime("result_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")    
    os.makedirs(f"{base_folder}/result_edit", exist_ok=True)
    
    filename = "video.mp4"
    #filename = "BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    
    video_duration = VideoFileClip(filename).duration

    number = 0 # instead of `cut_name_num` and `txt_part` because both had the same value

    time_start = time.time()
    
    all_processes = []
    for start in range(0, int(video_duration), 60):

        end = start + 60
        
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration
        
        number += 1
        
        print("add process:", number)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_process, args=(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder)) # it has to use `target=`, `args=`
        p.start()  # start it
        all_processes.append(p)  # keep it to use `join()`
            
    # - after loop -
    
    for p in all_processes:
        p.join()  # wait for the end of process
        
    # because I use `number += 1` before loop so now `number` has number of subclips
    print('number of subclips:', number)

    time_end = time.time()
    
    diff = time_end - time_start
    print(f'time: {diff:.2f}s ({diff//60:02.0f}:{diff%60:02.2f})')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Previous version for 11 subclips starts 11 processes. Using `Pool(4)` you can put all processes in pool and it will run 4 processes at the same time. When one process will finish task then it will start next process with new arguments.

This time I use loop to create list with arguments for all processes

```
args_for_all_processes = []

for start in range(0, int(video_duration), 60):

    end = start + 60
    
    if end > video_duration:
        end = video_duration
    
    number += 1
    print("add process:", number)
    
    args_for_all_processes.append( (filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder) )
```

and I use this list with `Pool` and it will do the rest.

```
# I have 4 CPU so I use Pool(4) - but without value it should automatically use `os.cpu_count()`
with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:      
    results = pool.starmap(my_process, args_for_all_processes)
    #print(results)
```

`Pool` may start processes in different order but if they use `return` to send some result then `Pool` will give results in correct order.

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
from moviepy.editor import *
import time
import multiprocessing

def my_process(filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder):

    clip_duration = end - start
    print(f'[DEBUG] number: {number:2} | start: {start:6.2f} | end: {end:6.2f} | duration: {clip_duration:.2f}')
    
    final_text = f"{number} {text}"

    temp_filename  = f"{base_folder}/cut_{number}.mp4"
    final_filename = f"{base_folder}/result_edit/cut_{number}.mp4"
    
    #print('[DEBUG] ffmpeg_extract_subclip')
    #ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, start, end, targetname=temp_filename)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] VideoClip')
    #clip = VideoFileClip(temp_filename)
    clip = VideoFileClip(filename).subclip(start, end)
    clip = clip.volumex(2)

    #print('[DEBUG] TextClip')
    txt_clip = TextClip(final_text, font="font/VarelaRound-Regular.ttf", fontsize=50, color='white')
    txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos(("center","top")).set_duration(60)
    
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip')
    video = CompositeVideoClip([clip, txt_clip])

    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip write')
    video.write_videofile(final_filename)
    #print('[DEBUG] CompositeVideoClip end')
    
    # return "OK"  # you can use `return` to send result/information to main process.
    
def main():

    text = input("Enter Your text please: ") [::-1]
    #text = 'Hello World'
    
    base_folder = time.strftime("result_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")    
    os.makedirs(f"{base_folder}/result_edit", exist_ok=True)
    
    filename = "video.mp4"
    #filename = "BigBuckBunny.mp4"
    
    video_duration = VideoFileClip(filename).duration

    number = 0 # instead of `cut_name_num` and `txt_part` because both had the same value

    time_start = time.time()
    
    # first create list with arguments for all processes
    
    args_for_all_processes = []
    
    for start in range(0, int(video_duration), 60):

        end = start + 60
        
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration
        
        number += 1
        print("add process:", number)
        
        args_for_all_processes.append( (filename, text, start, end, number, base_folder) )

    # - after loop -            
        
    # next put all processes to pool
        
    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:  # I have 4 CPU so I use Pool(4) - but it should use `os.cpu_count()` in `Pool()
    
        results = pool.starmap(my_process, args_for_all_processes)
        #print(results)
            
    # - after loop -
    
    # because I use `number += 1` before loop so now `number` has number of subclips
    print('number of subclips:', number)

    time_end = time.time()
    
    diff = time_end - time_start
    print(f'time: {diff:.2f}s ({diff//60:02.0f}:{diff%60:02.2f})')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Can you explain me why you did this?
        if end > video_duration:
            end = video_duration
I am a little confusing
because if i am taking a video that lets say 5:01 so its end in 5:00 and not in 5:01

Comment: last clip can be shorter then 60seconds - if you try to use `.subclip(start, end)` with `end` bigger then `video_duration` then it raises error.  Using `if` I get correct `end` value and I don't have to use `try/except`

Comment: Oh now I understand, i knew this but i forgot why i did  the try except, your way is better and less code, thank you

Comment: I know the code is working good, but i tried both code my and yours, and the code without the multiprocessing taking shorter then the other code. and i have a pretty good pc, the shorter one is 330 seconds and the other one 425 seconds, you know why?

Comment: in multiprocessing/threading it needs extra time to start process - if processes can't run at the same time (ie. one process gets all CPU power) then you get longer time. And ffmpeg (which is used in MoviPy) may get all CPU power in one process and it can make all problem. And this may not have solution.

Comment: How can i split the power for the each CPU?

Comment: or i just need to use a larger file, 40 minutes instead of 5 minutes, it will work faster?

Comment: I tested on 10 minutes file and I reduced time only by 20 seconds. I think `ffmpeg` may already use threadings on all cores and it can't work faster. [How many threads does ffmpeg use by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/155305/how-many-threads-does-ffmpeg-use-by-default)

Comment: I tried it on a 49 minutes file and its did the work very fast, for short videos i just should use the single process, i think maybe its did it faster then it did the 5 minutes video file.